# Not all colours are rendering with addLegend

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to add a bunch of colours to a legend in a leaflet map, however, some are not rendering. Using the available colours listed in `?makeAwesomeIcon`, the colours *lightred*, *beige* and *darkpurple* do not get added to the legend key (arguably something is added for the beige). Do you have any ideas how I can get these to work please?

[image]

Code:

```
library(leaflet)
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(lng=174.768 + runif(19, -0.1, 0.1), lat=-36.852 + runif(19, -0.1, 0.1))

# range of colours ?makeAwesomeIcon
df1$colour <- c("red", "darkred", "lightred", "orange", "beige", "green", "darkgreen", "lightgreen", "blue", "darkblue", "lightblue", 
                 "purple", "darkpurple", "pink", "cadetblue", "white", "gray", "lightgray", "black")

myIcons <- function(col) makeAwesomeIcon( icon='ion', markerColor=col )
iconS <- do.call(awesomeIconList, setNames(lapply(df1$colour, myIcons), df1$colour))

leaflet(df1) %>%
  addTiles() %>%  
  addAwesomeMarkers(icon = ~iconS[colour]) %>%
  # manual legend ?addLegend
  addLegend("bottomright", colors =~colour, labels=~colour)
```

Comment: Although `lightred` and `darkpurple` are listed as valid colours for `makeAwesomeIcon`, neither of them seems to be an R standard colour (as listed by `colors()`), so it seems that leaflet is using different palettes for the icons and for the legend (which is also presumably why the beige is a noticeably different shade). I'm not sure how to get round this.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGustar. I had noticed that `col2rgb("lightred")` was giving an error but I assumed that the *available* colours were getting passed to the javascript library and so not really dependent on R's (and general R colours do not render).  I just won't use these colours then.